# How to allow an executable file to launch a pdf when the sandbox Acrobat Reader XI blocks it

Tags: delphi

My setup.exe installs several files including an executable. 
When I ask this executable to launch a help file with "ShellExecute ... pdf", it happens nothing visible, but in the task manager, I can see that Acrobat Reader has been launched.
But it is stuck and can no more be launched, even manually until  I have removed the frozen process. 
What is the solution?

Comment: This would probably require a shell extension. Definitely not for the faint of heart. Are you sure you want to do this in the first place? Taking over ownership of the mouse cursor is usually frowned upon.

Comment: You can get its top-left position by `IFolderView::GetItemPosition` method. Oh, and of course you can also select an item when you'll be accessing `IFolderView` interface. @500, it's not that hard. You just query a few interfaces...

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do that, because: When my program is installed, it places some files in a folder, including an executable file that automatically launches a help file at the end of the installation.

Comment: This executable runs the classic "ShellExecute ... Aide.pdf ..." 
Everything worked fine under XP, W7, W8, W8.1 with Acrobat Reader up to version XI which now includes a reinforced protection.

Comment: But since, at the end of the install, the executable launches the command to show the pdf, but if, in Acrobat Reader, the enhanced protection is not disabled, nothing happens and the Reader is frozen and invisible.

Comment: It can be seen in the Task Manager, it has been launched but it is blocked, it will work again only if the process is deleted.By cons, once I started it manually, by double clicking on it, on this executable, all is working again normally. 
So I tell myself that if I make a command that executes by code, a double click of mouse on this exe, it could work.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible hack. There will be proper ways to cooperate with the Adobe Reader's [`protected mode`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html). Just a quick question (without reading through the linked help), are you opening that document (executing `ShellExecute`) from a setup which is running elevated with admin rights ? I'm asking because if you say that you can open it from Windows Explorer, I would suspect it's the admin elevation that causes the file to be sandboxed ?

Comment: If Acrobat Reader did not want to launch a pdf, because its enhanced protection want guarantees, I could understand. 
But, that it starts and stays froozen in the processes,  preventing fot the entire session to read other pdf and so to launch the Reader alone ! 
I'm just trying to solve a problem that Adobe asked ! 
In other words, a bug in the new version of Acrobat Reader XI.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I'll try it tomorrow. Yes, it's midnight now in France ! :-)

Comment: This is a classic XY question. I suggest that you change the question to ask about the underlying problem. Perhaps another problem you should be aware of is that your users might not have a PDF reader.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is not there. 
My program tests foremost if there is an application to open the pdf files, otherwise it will notify the user by a messagebox then he launches a text version. 
Moreover, this problem, I first met testing my software on my PC where Acrobat Reader is installed and works fine when we are not in this context.

Comment: The problem does not arise if it's another PDF reader that is set by default. 
It only occurs with Acrobat Reader XI, but I would like to find a solution because most users only use him.

Comment: Like I said, you should edit your question to ask about the actual problem, not your planned solution. There is a better solution than your planned solution. We cannot give you that solution until you ask the right question.

Comment: I rephrased my question, hoping to get an answer

Comment: Btw. which installer do you use ?

Comment: I use Smart Install Maker but I do not think it has a report. 
My setup.exe made ​​by Smart Intall Maker can not launch the help file at the end of the installation, because the sandbox blocks, but the prog  installed by the setup.exe can not, either, open a pdf with ShellExecute. 
If I do a double-click with the mouse on the executable, then all is ok now. 
But, my prog must be Launched by shorcuts, so it do not work if the user Effective facility is not gone in the folder once to double click on this executable.

Comment: But, my prog must be launched by shorcuts, so it don't work after installation if the user is not gone in the folder to double-clic once on this executable.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the issue is as discussed in the comments. Namely that the installer program runs as elevated administrator, and modern Acrobat Reader won't open documents when the process is executed as elevated administrator.

You can check this yourself quite easily with a simple program that contains a single call to `ShellExecute` to open the document in question. Run the program as standard user and see what happens with the call to `ShellExecute`. Then run the program as administrator and check that the document fails to open.

The solution is for you to run the program as standard user. That's not an easy thing to arrange from an elevated process. It involves quite a lot of furkling around. This MSDN article is the best source of information that I know of on the topic: [How do I start a program as the desktop user from an elevated app?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx) The code supplied is in C++ but since it is almost entirely Win32 API calls it should be a trivial conversion task.